# Is the collapse of a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space still totally disconnected?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $S$ be a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space and let $A\subset S$ be a closed subset. Let $S/A$ denote the space we get when collapsing $A$ to a point. Is this space still totally disconnected?

Comment: Yes indeed! Great, I didn't know this space. Thanks.

Comment: On second thoughts, why is it a collapse by a closed set? I understand, it is a collapse $S/A$ of some t.d. space $S$, but I can't get $A$ closed.

Comment: Yes, the quotient is totally disconnected. If you take two distinct points outside $A$, there are two clopen subsets disjoint of $A$ and separating them, hence at the quotient these map to clopen subsets, separating them. If you take a point outside $A$, there's a single clopen subset containing it and disjoint of $A$, and at the quotient this and its complement are two clopen subsets separating the two images.

Comment: @bof No clarification is needed: it is classical that in a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space (totally disconnected being in the usual sense: connected components are singletons), distinct points are separated by clopen subsets

Comment: @Ycor You say that a point outside $A$ can be separated from $A$ by a clopen set. Why is that? Urysohn gives you open or closed sets doing the job, but how to get a clopen set?

Comment: @Ycor I got it!

Comment: If we allow the collapse of infinitely many different closed sets, i.e. if $A\subset S\times S$ is closed equivalence relation, then the equivalence relation on the cantor set that identifies the two endpoints of each removed interval is a counterexample. In this case, the quotient is again the unit inverval.

Comment: To elaborate on @HenrikRüping's comment, every compact metric space $X$ can be written as $2^\Bbb N/R$ for some closed equivalence relation $R$, by picking a continuous surjection $f\colon 2^\Bbb N\to X$ and letting $xRy\iff f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: @YCor Isn't this an answer, not a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you take two distinct points outside $A$, there are two clopen subsets disjoint of $A$ and separating them, hence at the quotient these map to clopen subsets, separating them. If you take a point outside $A$, there's a single clopen subset containing it and disjoint of $A$, and at the quotient this and its complement are two clopen subsets separating the two images.

(I'm using that the image of a clopen subset is clopen as soon as it contains or is disjoint of $A$.)

A simple generalization is the following: if $X$ is totally disconnected compact Hausdorff, $A$ a closed subset, $A\to B$ a surjective continuous map to another totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space, then "collapsing $A$ to $B$" yields a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space.

Above is when $B$ is a singleton.

Comment: I think it's worth explicitly writing down that you use the facts that for compact Hausrdoff spaces, ⓐ “totally disconnected” and “totally separated” are equivalent, so we can separate distinct points by complementary clopen sets, and ⓑ regularity holds, so we can separate points from closed sets. This makes me wonder if the statement still holds when we remove “compact” (i.e., is the collapse of a closed set in a totally disconnected Hausdorff space still totally disconnected?).

Comment: (I feel like the answer to the last sentence in my previous comment *had* been answered in comments to the question itself which where then, sadly, deleted.)

Comment: Indeed. The idea (due to @bof) was to write the Knaster-Kuratowski fan as a quotient of a similar space where the top looks exaktly like the bottom,i.e. it is a Cantor set. and then one can divide out the top to get the fan.